# Storage place for CSS of custom 2sxc modules

Tags: css, dotnetnuke, 2sxc

we use DNN, 2sxc and write 2sxc-modules for our needs with the help of the 2sxc **Content** object.

In one DNN-installation we have several portals (websites), all portals share the same 2sxc and the same custom skin "XYZ".

Our 2sxc cshtml-templates are stored in the folder **Portals/_default/2sxc/Content/**, for example   *Portals/_default/2sxc/Content/history-module.cshtml*.

Our skin folder is **Portals/_default/Skins/XYZ/**. Our main CSS file is *Portals/_default/Skins/XYZ/xyz-skin.css*.

We are not sure what is the best place to store CSS of our 2sxc cshtml-templates, so the question is about it. For example:

1. Should the CSS of our custom History Module be stored directly in the `history-module.cshtml` in a `<style>....</style>`, so everything lays inside the 2sxc/Content/ folder?
2. Or should the CSS of our History Module rather be stored in our main CSS file `xyz-skin.css` inside the Skins-folder? Where the file "xyz-skin.css" is included in `Portals\_default\Skins\XYZ\footer_dnnincludes.inc.aspx` the following way:

```html
<dnn:DnnCssInclude ID="BootstrapCSS" runat="server" FilePath="assets/bootstrap-v4_3_1/bootstrap.min.css"  PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude ID="BootstrapJS" runat="server" FilePath="assets/bootstrap-v4_3_1/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />
<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="assets/js/xyz-main-js-file.js" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />
<dnn:DnnCssInclude ID="MainSkin" runat="server" FilePath="xyz-skin.css" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />
```

3. Or some other or mixed solution?

What is the correct way and what is best for the site performance?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to put the CSS in an own file inside the app folder of that specific app.

It should then only be loaded if needed. So the App should then make sure the CSS is loaded.

Please check out the many sample apps on 2sxc.org/apps like the blog, news, etc. There you can see how it's done.